# Django admin custom search on custom column

Tags: django-admin

Question:
How can I add the ability to search for items in my custom column Help Text?

FooAdmin View
[image: FooAdmin Page]

Code:
Here is a simplified version of the code that I am working with:

models.py (yes this is how the models need to be set up)

```py
class HelpText(models.Model):

    help_text = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.help_text

class Foo(models.Model):
    
    job_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=False)
    env = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.job_name

class FooHelpText(models.Model):
  
    foo = models.OneToOneField(Foo, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    help_text = models.ForeignKey(HelpText, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.help_text)
```

admin.py

```py
class FooHelpTextInline(admin.TabularInline):

    model = models.FooHelpText

@admin.register(models.Foo)
class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    search_fields = ['env', 'job_name',]

    list_display = ['pk', 'job_name', 'env', '_get_help_text', ]
    inlines = [FooHelpTextInline]


    def _get_help_text(self, obj):
        return obj.foohelptext.help_text
```

Current behavior:
The current code above allows me to see the associated help_text in a column on FooAdmin. However, I am not able to search by anything in that column.

Not the answer I am looking for:
I know if it was the other way around where the help_text was a ForeignKey on Foo I could do something like `foo__help_text`, but that is not how my models are set up (and can not change).

Desired behavior:
Use the search box to search for help text (not just env and job_name).

Possible Solution (that I need help with):
I suspect that [get_search_results](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_search_results) might be what I need, but I don't understand how to implement it for my use case.

UPDATE:
The closest I can get is searching for a number(aka a specific PK that I know exists) and getting that search result. But the query doesn't really make sense. And obviously that is not the desired functionality of a search.

```py
    def get_search_results(self, request, queryset, search_term):
        queryset, use_distinct = super().get_search_results(request, queryset, search_term)
        try:
            search_term_as_int = int(search_term)
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            queryset |= models.Foo.objects.select_related(
                'foohelptext').filter(fooshelptext=search_term_as_int)
        return queryset, use_distinct
```

I just don't understand the Python |= (bitwise OR operator) and why it has to be an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much easier than I thought. No need for `get_search_results`. 
Simply needed to add it as `foohelptext__help_text__help_text` as an other item in the search fields.